# spring sleuth @NewSpan annotation at the jpa repository level

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, distributed-tracing

Problem: I could not enable my jpa repository interface with this annotation. It complains `'@NewSpan' not applicable to type`. I guess, it just does not work with interfaces and needs the concrete implementation which is not good for dynamically generated jpa functions. Any pointers or solutions?